# Random break,pass and continue statements Python

Tags: python, loops, random

I'm trying to randomly break and pass loop but `random.choice([pass,break])` just won't work and shows invalid syntax.
Any Suggestions..?

Comment: Can you add your code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `pass` and `break` as arguments in `random.choice`, python thinks they are variable names. But they're not.

```py
res = random.choice(['pass','break'])
if res == 'pass':
  pass
if res == 'break':
  break
```